# Probability raffle?

Tags: probability

Thirty tickets are sold in a raffle. There are two prizes (first and second). Lewis buys 4 tickets. What is the probability of him winning the second prize but not the first?

Answer (score 2):

Of the $30$ tickets, $1$ is first prize, $1$ is second prize, and $28$ are no prize. Of the $4$ tickets Lewis buys, $0$ are first prize, $1$ is second prize, and $3$ are no prize. So we obtain:
$$
\frac{\binom{1}{0}\binom{1}{1}\binom{28}{3}}{\binom{30}{4}}
= \frac{52}{435}
$$

Comment: @trueblueanil you right I got it...thanks

Answer (score 2):

The chance that Lewis doesn't win on the first draw (first prize) is $$1-\frac{4}{30} = \frac{26}{30}$$

Given that Lewis didn't win on the first draw, there are $29$ tickets remaining, and Lewis has $4$ of them, so the chance that Lewis wins on the second draw (second prize), but not on the first, is
$$\left(\frac{26}{30}\right)\left(\frac{4}{29}\right) = \frac{52}{435}$$